# having trouble connecting auth.services.adobe.com

Tags: adobe, behance-api

I get an error when trying to log in to adobe, behance, etc. on my mac. Another computer in the same house logs in. I can even log in from my phone. what could be the problem?

thank you in advance for your support

**Error code;**

Failed to connect

An error occurred during the connection to auth.services.adobe.com.

```
The site may be temporarily down or very busy. Wait a moment and try again.
If you can't open any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is allowed to access the web.
```

Another computer in the same house logs in. I can even log in from my phone.